# Alaskan Bears Probability

Tags: probability-distributions

One of the popular tourist attractions in Alaska
is watching black bears catch salmon swimming upstream
to spawn. Not all “black” bears are black, though—
some are tan-colored. Suppose that six black bears and
three tan-colored bears are working the rapids of a
salmon stream. Over the course of an hour, six different
bears are sighted. What is the probability that those six
include at least twice as many black bears as tan-colored
bears?
I don't understand how to do this problem, i know i have to use hypo geometric distribution but i don't know how. There was another post like this question but the answer given unfortunately didn't help

Comment: We want $6$-$0$ or $5$-$1$ or $4$-$2$. Find the probability for each, and add up.  More easily, compute the probability of $3$ blacks and $3$ tans, and subtract from $1$.

Comment: Would we not need to subtract 4 states from 1 if that should work: 3-3, 2-4,1-5 and 0-6?

Comment: @mathreadler - there are only three tan bears.

Comment: Are the bears captured? It says in the question they are "sighted" which would be more like pulling teddy bears out of a basket on random but then putting them back again.

Answer (score 0):

So a very partial solution and hint due to lack of time, not in unbearable danger though. Will expand later ( wished there was a way to save partial answers )

First part of the problem is to decide how much is required for "at least twice as many". We can write this as equation system

$$\begin{align}x+y =& 6\\y - 2x \geq& 0\end{align}$$

If we solve the system with equality, we get $x = 2, y = 4$.
So $y\geq4$ which means $y\in\{4,5,6\}$

Then we check how the [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution works.